# howto iterate dynamic array

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have the following json string

```
[{"field1":"1","field2":"2","field3":"3"}{"field1":"11","field2":"22","field3":"33"}{"field1":"111","field2":"222","field3":"333"}]
```

I use the following code to parse it -

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(s);
```

How can I iterate the dynamic data array ?

Comment: Try `foreach (dynamic x in data)`.

Comment: If you use newtonsoft.json you can actually deserialize this as a collection of JObjects

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Deserialize
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("dynamic.json");

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            dynamic data = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                foreach (var subitem in item)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Key={0}, Value={1}", subitem.Key, subitem.Value);
                }

                System.Console.WriteLine();
            }

            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add commas to separate the 3 objects in the json file for this to work ... but I think this is (roughly) what you are after. Sorry if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Problem is it says cannot iterate data because  is not IEnummerable ...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code.

```
List<myClass> l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myClass>>(jsonString);
```

Than I had no problem iterate through l.

myClass is a local class with the field definition, need to make sure field and class defined public.